# Deny access to specific roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a folder UserManagement with role based access and is as below.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow roles="UserAdmin_M"/>
    <allow roles="UserAdmin_MC"/>
    <deny roles="ReportsAdmin"/>
  </authorization>
```

Admin will have access to other folders as well like reports.
Now the problem is, I'm having an user "TestUser" with roles UserAdmin_M and ReportsAdmin but the application is blocking the access to "UserManagement" folder for TestUser. How to overcome this?

Comment: i've used this in the past, i seem to recall that it had something to do with the order of the roles, and that the deny role is always on a higher priority then an allow role.

Comment: Yes, Its all about order of the roles. I was thinking deny should come first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but could this have something to do with the order in which you have assigned the roles to your user? From MSDN it states:

> At run time, the authorization module iterates through the allow and deny elements, starting at the most local configuration file, until the authorization module **finds the first access rule that fits a particular user account**. Then, the authorization module grants or denies access to a URL resource depending on whether the first access rule found is an allow or a deny rule.

Make sure you are assigning the `UserAdmin_M` role before the `ReportsAdmin` rule.

FYI - you can comma separate roles in your configuration:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow roles="UserAdmin_M, UserAdmin_MC" />
    <deny roles="ReportsAdmin" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comma separation information. I was not knowing about that. This worked.